# An answer was assigned to a different question

Tags: bug

I'm not sure if this would be better suited somewhere else, but I figure someone here will know if that's so...

I just went to a question, read it, and created an answer without leaving the page - I posted the answer and the page refreshed as normal, but showed no answers, even if I returned to the list of questions and tried again.  I cleared my browser cache to see if it was just a cache problem, but when I logged back in, I noticed the answer I had given to Question A, was assigned to a different question.  I subsequently deleted that answer, and re-tried answering the original question, which worked without issue.  Obviously this was a fluke, but could be the symptom of a system issue.

The question I was answering is [Can I create a view that combines multiple images from single node with images from other nodes that entity reference the original node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157513/can-i-create-a-view-that-combines-multiple-images-from-single-node-with-images-f) The question where I found my answer is https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157512/how-to-have-a-stack-of-frontpage-views-to-choose-from

Comment: May you link the questions you are referring in the question?

Comment: that was a week and a half ago, I don't recall the two questions involved, but based on the time of this question and my answers log, I would assume the answer I wrote was for this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157513/can-i-create-a-view-that-combines-multiple-images-from-single-node-with-images-f/157516   but the other question seemed random, and I don't recall which one it was

Comment: I found it. I will update the question here with links to both the questions.